# Google Analytics and Colorbox - Cross domain tracking

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, cross-domain, colorbox

With our GA code, we are tracking multiple domains and subdomains, and we have the main bulk of the code tracking properly with only a couple of self-referrals. The biggest issue revolves around the fact that we use [Colorbox](http://jacklmoore.com/colorbox/) for modal windows, and I need to be able to attach code to these pages to eliminate self referrals.

I've done a lot of searching, and working around in JavaScript to find a work-around, with no luck.

If I add `onClick="_gaq.push(['_link', $(this).attr('href')]);return false;"` to the a tag to open the modal window, when the page refreshes with the attach querystring params from Google, it breaks out of the modal window and takes over the entire browser window. I've tried building a custom function rather than just a straight onclick, and I get the same result. The only reference I have found is [this article from 2010](https://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!category-topic/analytics/discuss-tracking-and-implementation-issues/vNK4NP5Jm_s).

I'm at a loss here. I was thinking maybe I could grab the utmcc info pre-link and append it to the URL ahead of time, with no luck on finding a way to grab that from the session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code I ended up using, thanks to yahelc for the help.

```
$('.link-btn').bind("cbox_complete", function(){
    var pageTracker = _gat._getTrackerByName();
    var href = $.colorbox.element().attr('href');
    if (href) {
        _gaq.push(function() {
          var pageTracker = _gat._getTrackerByName();
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('#cboxLoadedContent iframe').attr('src',pageTracker._getLinkerUrl(href));
            },1000);
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`_link` is a convenience wrapper over [`_getLinkerUrl`.](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gaJS/gaJSApiDomainDirectory.html#_gat.GA_Tracker_._getLinkerUrl)

You can just convert the URL to have the linker dynamically in JavaScript without using the convenience function (which in this case is inconvenient). (Assuming jQuery, since you're using colorbox).

Assuming the markup on that link is something like `<a href="..." class="colorboxlink">Click!</a>`...

```
   $(".colorboxlink").each(function(){
        $(this).attr('href', function(i,v){
                 return _gat._getTrackerByName()._getLinkerUrl(v);
         });
   });
```

I'd only recommend this approach if it's no more than 1 or 2 links; for a large number of links (20+), it can have performance impacts. Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/XscWT/

Comment: Thanks. That's along the lines of what I was looking for - the only thing is that it looks like it's not carrying over the same user cookie, but generating a new one for the new page. Am I understanding how this works incorrectly? I'm using httpwatch and fiddler to snoop the results. You also need to have parens around 'this' - '`$(this)`

Comment: Hm, try wrapping the code in a `_gaq.push(function(){  ...  });` after the `_trackPageview` call (assuming the async syntax)

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what code to wrap. The entire block? I've tried a couple of variants and it ceases firing at all if I wrap it in that function....