# Google Analytics and Colorbox iframe - Cross domain tracking

Tags: jquery, html, google-analytics, colorbox

I'm stuck on the following issue.

I have a page with an enquiry button that launches a contact form an iframe in a colorbox.

The main page is on www.domain1.com and the iframe is on www.domain2.com

I don't have a full understanding of how Google Analytics treats multiple domains, but I was led to believe that GA can accept the domain2.com tracking information in the domain1.com GA account. Please clarify if I'm wrong.

This is the code im trying to use to pass the cookies from domain1 to domain2

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

        $(document).bind('cbox_complete', function(){
            console.log ('Passed to iframe');
            var pageTracker = _gat._getTrackerByName();
            var href = $.colorbox.element().attr('href');
            if (href) {
                _gaq.push(function() {
                  var pageTracker = _gat._getTrackerByName();
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        $('#cboxLoadedContent iframe').attr('src',pageTracker._getLinkerUrl(href));
                        console.log (pageTracker._getLinkerUrl(href));
                    },1000);
                });
            }
        }); 
    });
```

I've tried a solution like this: [Google Analytics and Colorbox - Cross domain tracking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8932016/google-analytics-and-colorbox-cross-domain-tracking)

Comment: Are you using ga.js or analytics.js? Ie, the classic analytics or universal? The gaq.push are for the old syntax used in Classic Analytics.